# Regular expression and pattern matching inside LIST

Tags: python, list

I have a list of file names in my current working directory.

```
my_list = ["apple.txt","mango.txt", "grapes.txt","draw.png" , "hello123.txt" , "figure.png"]
```

Now I would like to create a new list which stores only `*.txt` files:

```
new_list = ["apple.txt","mango.txt", "grapes.txt", "hello123.txt"]
```

Is there any way to achieve this using regular expression and pattern matching in Python.

Comment: Pattern matching and regex are rather irrelevant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1** with `regex`.

```
import re
txt_regex = re.compile(r'(\w+.txt)')
my_list = ["apple.txt","mango.txt", "grapes.txt","draw.png" , "hello123.txt" , "figure.png"]
result = [i for i in my_list if txt_regex.match(i)]
```

[Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2D9z3JENZxvvg4M7) of regex.

**Method 2** with `os`

```
from os.path import splitext
result = [i for i in my_list if splitext(i)[1] == '.txt']
```

**Method 3** with `split`

```
result = [i for i in my_list if i.split('.')[1] in '.txt']
```

**Ouput**

```
['apple.txt', 'mango.txt', 'grapes.txt', 'hello123.txt']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this :

```
new_list = [name for name in my_list if name.endswith('.txt')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also:

```
new_list = []
for file in my_list:
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        new_list.append(file)
print(new_list)
```

Output

```
['apple.txt', 'mango.txt', 'grapes.txt', 'hello123.txt']
```

UPDATE:

You can also group all the files using a defaultdict, like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for file in my_list:
    key = "." + file.split(".")[1]
    d[key].append(file)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'.txt': ['apple.txt', 'mango.txt', 'grapes.txt', 'hello123.txt'], '.png': ['draw.png', 'figure.png']})
```

Or even with out a defaultdict:

```
d = {}
for file in my_list:
    key = "." + file.split(".")[1]
    if key not in d:
       d[key] = []
    d[key].append(file)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'.txt': ['apple.txt', 'mango.txt', 'grapes.txt', 'hello123.txt'], '.png': ['draw.png', 'figure.png']}
```

Comment: This is only catch if it have extension of length 3.

Comment: I mean if an extension `.docx` this method is not work. My point is it's  hard coding method.